# How to get disabled dropdownlist value pass into controller in asp.net core mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

> In disabled mydropdown list in some reason. but need to pass the value
> to controller but in controller dropdownlist selected value comes to
> null. how can i get disabled dropdown value.
>
> My html code:

```
<select asp-for="Type" title="Type" class="form-control form-control-sm border selectpicker"
                                            " id="Type" disabled>
                                        <option value="Invoice" selected="selected">Invoice</option>
```

> Controller Post Action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Bill(Bill bill, ActionType actionType)
        {
}
```

> bill.Type value return null. because disabled html value returns null.
> but i need get the disabled dropdown value.

Comment: You will not get the value in the controller from the disabled control. You can try to create a hidden field and try to assign the dropdown value to the hidden field before disabling the dropdown. If the drop-down is disabled on page load then you can try to get the value from ViewModel. `model => model.MySelectedItem`. [Reference](https://forums.asp.net/t/1846952.aspx?Disabled+DropDownListFor+reports+null+for+selected+value+).

Comment: ok. i will check it.